# Once a user visits a [RequireHTTPS] action, they stay on https

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm securing some of my ActionResults with `[RequireHttps]` and that's working great.

People are keeping their https connection after they go to other links.  I only want https on certain pages that I specify, I want http on everything else.

Comment: Are you applying it to the class or individual actionresults?

Comment: The class, but people are going to other controllers.  So SignupController has Requirehttps, but HomeController doesn't.

Comment: Try changing that. Use `[RequireHttps]` on only those `ActionResult` where you want ssl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a base controller and override the `OnActionExecuting` method to do something like:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx) {
{
    bool redirect = true;
    if (!ctx.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection) redirect = false;

    // Bypass if [RequireHttps] is applied
    if (ctx.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes
        (typeof(RequireHttpsAttribute), true).Length > 0) redirect = false;
    if (ctx.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes
        (typeof(RequireHttpsAttribute), true).Length > 0) redirect = false;

    if (!redirect)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(ctx);
    }
    else
    {
        // Redirect to HTTP
        string url = "http://" + ctx.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host 
            + ctx.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;

        ctx.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
    }
}
```